# How are 'primitive recursive' sets defined?

Tags: set-theory

The following is taken from *Inner Models and Large Cardinals* by Martin Zeman (beginning of chapter 2).
Let $\kappa$ be an ordinal. $U \subseteq \mathcal P(\kappa)$ is *suitable* iff

1. $\kappa$ is primitive recursively closed and
2. If $A_1, \ldots, A_n \in U$, $\nu_1, \ldots, \nu_m \in \kappa$ and $B$ is primitive recursive in the predicates $A_1, \ldots, A_n$ and the parameters $\nu_1, \ldots, \nu_m$, then $B \cap \kappa \in U$.

While it isn't defined by the author, I'm fairly certain that "$\kappa$ being primitive recursively closed" means that for every $\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_n < \kappa$ and every [primitive recursive ordinal function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_recursive_set_function) $f(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ we have that $f(\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_n) < \kappa$.

**Question 1** Am I right about being a primitive recursively closed ordinal?

I'm less certain that I understand property 2. What does $B$ being primitive recursive in the predicates $A_1, \ldots, A_n$ and parameters $\nu_1, \ldots, \nu_m$ mean? I guess it means the following:

There is a primitive recursive set function $f(x_0, x_1, \ldots, x_n, y_1, \ldots, y_m)$ such that $B = \{x \mid f(x,A_1, \ldots, A_n, \nu_1, \ldots, \nu_m) \neq \emptyset \}$. (In general $B$ is then a proper class, but that doesn't concern me, since I'm only interested in $B \cap \kappa$ anyways.)

**Question 2** Is this the definition Martin Zeman had in mind?

---

edit: Should anyone in the future stumble upon this question: There is now a typed script by Jensen on Fine Structure available on [Ronald Jensen's website](http://www.mathematik.hu-berlin.de/~raesch/org/jensen/pdf/TheSkript.pdf) or [Ralf Schindler's website](http://wwwmath.uni-muenster.de/logik/Personen/rds/jensen_script.pdf). It's still under early development and will be extended and corrected. Right now the relevant information can be found on page 19ff.

Comment: Q1: yes essentially. say $\kappa$ is p.r closed iff $L_{\kappa}$ is p.r closed (i.e $L_{\kappa}$ is closed under applications of p.r functions).

Comment: For Q2: that is essentially it, except you would let $f$ be p.r in the predicates $A_1,...A_n$ i.e p.r in their characteristic functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a good chance that these primitive recursive functions come from the fine structure setting and are the same as those defined in Jensen's notes: http://www.mathematik.hu-berlin.de/~raesch/org/jensen/pdf/AS_2.pdf

Let $\bar{x} = (x_1, ..., x_n)$. It is the smallest class generated by the following schemes:

(1) For each $i$, the projection function is primitive recursive: $p_i(\bar{x}) = x_i$.

(2) The pairing function. Let $i,j < n$, then $\mathrm{pair}_{i,j}(\bar{x}) = \{x_i, x_j\}$.

(3) Composition: Suppose $h : V^k \rightarrow V$, and $g_1, ..., g_k : V^n \rightarrow V$ are primitive recursive functions, then $f(\bar{x}) = h(g_1(\bar{x}), ..., g_k(\bar{x}))$ is a primitive recursive function.

(4) Suppose $g(\bar{x}, y)$ is a primitive recursive function, then so is $f(\bar{x},y) = \bigcup_{z \in y} g(\bar{x},z)$.

(5) Primitive recursion: Suppose $g(\bar{x}, y, v)$ is primitive recursive, then so is $f(\bar{x},y) = g(\bar{x}, y, \langle f(\bar{x},z) : z \in y\rangle)$.

---

A set $A$ is primitive recursive closed if for all $f$ primitive recursive and all $\bar{x}$ which are tuples from $A$, $f(\bar{x}) \in A$.

Comment: Thank you. Before posting my question, I tried to get hold of a paper by Jensen and Karp where they introduced these notions, but so far I wasn't able to find it. In any case, between your answer and Carlo's comment I found the information I was looking for.